# Overlay image on other non-fixed pos image?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to overlay a picture on top of another picture via the ::after pseudo-element? I'm doing a personnel database as a school project and I want to indicate subsequent awards via an overlaying image on top of the older one.

HTML:

```
<div class="awardRow">
    <span id="awardAbbrev" class="award2"><img src="path/to/image.png"></span>
    <span id="awardAbbrev2" class="award2"><img src="path/to/image.png"></span>
    <span id="awardAbbrev3" class="award2"><img src="path/to/image.png"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.award2::after {
    content: url(imageToOverlay.png);
    position: relative;
    left: -110px;
}
```

I've tried several other methods to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: give position to your img i.e relative, absolute and use the z-index property.

Answer (score 1):

I have made this for you, go through this code you will understand.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .box {
        width: 175px;
        height: 175px;
        color: blue;
        border: 2px solid blue;
      }

      #box1 {
        background-color: aqua;
        position: absolute;
        top: 228%;
        left: 45%;
      }

      #box2 {
        background-color: rgb(145, 255, 0);
        position: absolute;
        top: 70%;
        left: 15%;
      }

      #box3 {
        background-color: rgb(255, 0, 68);
        position: absolute;
        top: 147%;
        left: 30%;
      }

      #box4 {
        background-color: rgb(255, 238, 0);
      }

      .container {
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box" id="box1"></div>
      <div class="box" id="box2"></div>
      <div class="box" id="box3"></div>
      <div class="box" id="box4"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this although it doesn't seem to factor in that the awards won't always be on the same location on the page. It's basically supposed to be a dynamic ribbon rack where the awards are collected from a database and depending on the amount of awards you'll have anywhere between 1-3 award ribbons in a single row.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the award image the background of the pseudo-element as follows:

```
<style>
    .award2 {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:bottom;
    }
    .award2 img {
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:bottom;
    }
    .award2::after {
        content:'';
        background:url('https://picsum.photos/50') no-repeat center bottom;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        height:50px;
    }
</style>

<div class="awardRow">
    <span id="awardAbbrev" class="award2"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200"></span>
    <span id="awardAbbrev2" class="award2"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200"></span>
    <span id="awardAbbrev3" class="award2"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200"></span>
</div>
```

Please let me know if this helps :)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem applicable for my project due to the involvement of PHP and SQL in the mix in the end product, but thank you anyways!